# Python Selenium, setting an executable path for webdriver makes other code not affect the webbrowser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I am very new to python selenium and I ran into a problem when I tried making my webdriver.firefox open up a specific firefox path. I am doing this so the firefox webdriver will keep all of my normal firefox settings.

I am honestly just stuck on what to do here, I've written most of my program without this setting and I tried learning a bit more on profiles (hoping this could be a way to solve my program, but I had no luck). I cannot find any resources on how to solve this problem, so any help would be appreciated

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
driver.get("https://youtube.com")
```

Basically, once I get driver and it starts up, the firefox webbrowser is my own browser with my settings, but any commands after this will not affect the browser. So, doing this code without the executable_path will open up a default browser without my settings and then go to youtube.com. With my code, the program opens up my browser but does nothing else.

I'm fine with any solution as long as I can open up my browser with my settings attached.

Any ideas on why this is and how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: To be more specific, this code will open up my firefox browser with my default browser settings. So, it opens up firefox to my default homepage as if I simply clicked on the firefox.exe, except the script will just crash with this error message:

```
 File "FinalProjectCode_No_Def.py", line 80, in <module>
    firefox = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service D:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the geckodriver (firefox webdriver) unzip the zip file and set the executable path geckodriver.exe .

Link to download the driver :- https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: That doesn't work for me. The problem isn't that geckodriver isn't working, it's more that opening a firefox browser seems to open a firefox browser from my C: drive instead of my D:drive. At least, that's what I suspect is happening because the firefox being open isn't the one I use. I just need a way to open up the firefox browser from my D: drive path instead of my C: drive path

Comment: Try using webdriver-manager :- https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Comment: I looked at that readme, and correct me if I miss something, but this seems to be a java only thing.